# jQuery fadeIn effect not working

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

I'm trying to load the page with the text `Welcome back!` in the div and then after 10 seconds fade it out and change text to `Account Dashboard` and then fade in.

This is what I'm using currently:

```
$('.recover_back_top_title').fadeIn().html("Welcome back!").delay(10000).fadeOut().delay(10000).html("Account Dashboard").fadeIn();
```

Currently all it does it just instantly go to the end and set the text to Account Dashboard without doing any effects. Am I missing something?

There is nothing showing in console for errors either.

Comment: how can i fade in text, fade it out, change it, and fade it back in again then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a function to [`fadeIn`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/#fadeIn-duration-complete) / [`fadeOut`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#fadeOut-duration-complete) which will be called after the animation has finished

```js
$('.recover_back_top_title').fadeIn(function() {
  $(this).html("Welcome back!")
         .delay(2000)
         .fadeOut(function() {
           $(this).delay(2000)
                  .html("Account Dashboard")
                  .fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="recover_back_top_title"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified Andreas' answer a little bit to add more ease in its fade:

```
$('.recover_back_top_title').fadeIn("slow",function() {
  $(this).html("Welcome back!")
         .delay(2000)
         .fadeOut("slow",function() {
           $(this).delay(2000)
                  .html("Account Dashboard")
                  .fadeIn();
  });
});
```

You can play around the delays.